# Is it possible to change the href of a link?

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have a link:

```
<a id="downloadLink">Donwload Link</a>
```

And a JavaScript function:

```
function ac(){document.getElementById('downloadLink').href = "CS352ProjectProposalRequirements.pdf";}
```

However when I call the function it doesn't work. It gives an error:

> Cannot change the property of null "href"

How can I dynamically change the `href` of a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're getting an error because `href` is not initially defined in your link. If you give it a default value initially (e.g. - #), you can change it later with JS.

Answer (score 1):

`<a id="downloadLink href="#" >DOWNLOAD</a>`.
This will fix the problem.

Comment: This would have been +1 is your grammar and styling was better. Try using code tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can change or create the HREF attribute dynamically by using something like this:

```
document.getElementById('downloadlLink').attributes["href"] = "yourlink";
```